# How to convert integer to text for usage in textfield java-blackberry

Tags: parsing, blackberry

I want to use an integer value in a `TextField`. In the below code I am retrieving integer value from table into `textfield3`. When I use `getInteger(2)` it is giving error. So what would be the alternative. If parsing is the solution (e.g. `.toString`) how is it to be implemented in this approach?

```java
TextField3 = new TextField("Amount: ",r.getString(2));
add(TextField3);
```

This is what I am exactly trying to do

```java
try
{
    //Open or create the database
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db");    

    //Retrieval
    Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("SELECT date,name,amount,narration FROM Bills where id='"+TextField00.getText()+"'");
    //This is one text field to accept id value
    statement1.prepare();
    statement1.execute();

    Cursor c = statement1.getCursor();
    Row r;

    while(c.next())
    {
        r = c.getRow();
        TextField5 = new TextField("Date: ",r.getString(0));
        add(TextField5); 

        TextField2 = new TextField("Customer Name: ",r.getString(1));
        add(TextField2);

        TextField3 = new TextField("Amount: ",r.getString(2));
        add(TextField3);

        TextField4 = new TextField("Narration: ",r.getString(3));
        add(TextField4);
    }

    //statement1.prepare();
    //statement1.execute();       
    statement1.close(); 
    db.close();
}
catch( Exception e ) 
{         
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it aids your understanding.

Comment: Your question is confusing. There is no constructor of `TextField` like what you are using, and return type of `r.getString(2)` is not given. Explain your question.

Comment: rupak check out the edited piece of code

Comment: Are you getting compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: If i use the exact above piece of code,only first 2 textfields are shown in emulator.On observing the console i can see that it shows a "datatype mismatch" which is clearing coming coz of the int thing.On commenting out the textfield3 i get the narration field as thats text.Also on changing the table schema to accept text for amount it shows.Please aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line,

```java
TextField3 = new TextField("Amount: ", r.getInteger(2) + "");
```

Instead of

```java
TextField3 = new TextField("Amount: ",r.getString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.Integer.toString()`:

```
TextField3 = new TextField("Amount: ", Integer.toString(r.getInteger(2)));
```

Comment: dis may work too i beleieve..but the above ans wrks perfect.Thanks for the answer though.